# Why isn't there equality in the definition of (upper) semicontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, definition, limsup-and-liminf

The "standard" definition of upper semicontinuity at a point $x_0$ in a metric space seems to be

$\limsup_{x\to x_{0}} f(x)\le f(x_0)$.

However, why is it this weaker condition instead of

$\limsup_{x\to x_{0}} f(x)= f(x_0)$  ?

For example, with right continuity we have

$\limsup_{\{x\ge x_0\}} f(x)=f(x_0)$.

Compare this situation with the four Dini derivatives (lower left, upper left, upper right, lower right). A function is right differentiable at a point if and only if its upper right and lower right Dini derivatives exist and coincide.

Analogously, a function is right continuous at $x_0$ if and only if its lower right and upper right limits exist, coincide, and agree with the value of the function at $x_0$.

So why would we want to define upper semicontinuity as "upper left and upper right limits exist, do not have to coincide, and are less than or equal to the value of f at $x_0$?".

Wouldn't the definition "upper left and upper right limits exist, coincide, and agree with the value of f at $x_0$" be either more natural or more useful?

Comment: This is really stupid, but it just occurred to me that the names are "upper/lower ***semi***continuous", i.e. _not_ "upper/lower continuous", so that an analogy with "right/left" continuity wouldn't even be expected anyway -- it would make more sense to define "upper continuity" to be the stronger condition $\lim\sup_{x \to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)$ than to define "upper ***semi***continuity" to be that -- the "semi" part could be understood to reflect the weaker condition implied by demanding only inequality than equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among the useful properties of semicontinuity is that the infimum of any collection of upper semicontinuous functions is upper semicontinuous.  In fact, on a metric space this characterizes the upper semicontinuous functions: every u.s.c. function is the infimum of a sequence of continuous functions.  This would not be the case with your proposed new property.  For example, the function 
$$ f(x) = \cases{1 & if $x = 0$\cr
                0 & otherwise\cr}$$
is the infimum of the continuous functions $\exp(-n x^2)$ for integers $n$, so we want this to be upper semicontinuous.

Comment: That makes sense. But isn't the definition a little too broad though?

For example, couldn't we take any bounded function (say $\le 1$), as horribly discontinuous as we might like, but then define f(0)=2, and then f would be upper semi-continuous at x=0?

Comment: Why is this too broad?  The horrible discontinuities elsewhere might make it not u.s.c. elsewhere, but are not relevant to the fact that this is u.s.c. at $0$.

Comment: That is a good point; we only want/need to define a local property, not a global one (e.g. uniform continuity).

I guess what is confusing for me is the comparison with right-continuity, because the right-continuous extension of a function defined on a countable dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$ would be continuous almost everywhere, and right-continuous on the null set, whereas the upper semi-continuous extension would not have to be continuous almost everywhere (but it would be for the definition I proposed).

Which is only an aesthetic objection and not a practical one.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Right continuity of a function $f$ has to do with order properties of the domain of $f$, while upper  semicontinuity has to do with the order properties of the range of $f$. So the analogy between the two concepts, vis-a-vis a.e. continuity,  is not that strong.